# Load .zip file from GitHub in Google Colab

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I have a zip file at my GitHub repo. I want to load it into my Google Colab files. I have it's url from where it can be dowloaded like `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rehmatsg/../master/...zip`

I used this method to download file into Google Colab

```py
from google.colab import files

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/.../master/...zip'
files.download(url)
```

But I get this error

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-c974a89c0412> in <module>()
      3 from google.colab import files
      4 
----> 5 files.download(url)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/files.py in download(filename)
    141       raise OSError(msg)
    142     else:
--> 143       raise FileNotFoundError(msg)  # pylint: disable=undefined-variable
    144 
    145   comm_manager = _IPython.get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager

FileNotFoundError: Cannot find file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/.../master/...zip
```

Files in Google Colab are temporary, so I cannot upload it each time. This is the reason I wanted to host the file in my project's GitHub repo.
What would be the correct method to download the file into Google Colab?

Comment: Looking at your link, your first one has the username, `rehmatsg`. The second one has `user`. So I think the issue here is that you provided the wrong URL.

Comment: No, actually my url is working. This one in my question is just an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that i.e. GitHub repo https://github.com/lukyfox/Datafiles contains folder *digits* with two zip files *digits.zip* and *digits_small.zip*. To download and unzip certain zip file from GitHub repo (not the whole repo or folder, but only digits.zip) into Google Colab session storage:

1. go to zip file you want to download (i.e. https://github.com/lukyfox/Datafiles/blob/master/digits/digits.zip)
2. Locate button Download and copy its address (RMB->Copy link address), for the example above copied address is https://github.com/lukyfox/Datafiles/raw/master/digits/digits.zip
3. Go to Google colab file and use `!wget` command with the copied address to download and `!unzip` to unzip the file into session storage:

`!wget https://github.com/lukyfox/Datafiles/raw/master/digits/digits.zip`
`!unzip /content/digits.zip`

You can also rename the file after download or specify folder name for unzipped data.

You may notice that the dowloadable address differs from zip file address just a little. In fact should be enough to replace *blob* with *raw* to get the right address  for  any zip file.

Answer (score 7):

Use the "wget" bash command. Just open the Github project and go to the download as zip option (at top right). Then, copy the url and use "wget" command.

`!wget https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/archive/refs/heads/master.zip`

`!unzip /content/master.zip`

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to clone the entire repository.

```
!git clone https://personalaccesstoken@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

This creates a folder called `reponame` and is convenient if you have many files to download. The `personalaccesstoken` allows private repositories to be accessed.

Comment: Repository contains many large files. It would not be feasible to download the whole repo.

Comment: The downloading happens quickly in my experience and there are many Gb of space you can utilise.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Google Colab, but I looked at this [description](https://neptune.ai/blog/google-colab-dealing-with-files). Understand that the `google.colab.download` option is to download Google Colab files. It's not for downloading any file. If this file is public you can use other libraries to retrieve the file. For example, you can use `urllib`:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve(url)
```

If you decide you need more files and use the code, then consider the other answer about `git clone`